# Nuxt: cannot watch data changing with useLazyFetch

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to watch for the value changing of a useLazyFetch call as in the docs (https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-fetch) but it seems it does not work:

```
const { data, pending, error: err, refresh } = await useLazyFetch('/api/posts');
watch(err, newErr => {
  console.error('error', newErr, err);
});

watch(data, newData => {
  console.log('data', data, newData);
});
```

Nothing is logged into the console while data and errors are correctly displayed into the template.

Have somebody encountered the same issue ?

See https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elegant-neco-cnr49p?file=%2Fapp.vue%3A10%2C19

Comment: Your question will be much more "answerable" if you provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem

Comment: I added a codesandbox example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing any logs in the console is the feature of Nuxt called in the docs as [Network calls duplication](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#network-calls-duplication)

When the Nuxt app is running in universal mode (SSR), every use of `useFetch` or `useLazyFetch` will request the data on the server 1st - Nuxt makes sure that this data fetched on the server will be sent together with rendered HTML to the client. So when the client executes the same `useFetch` call (matched by the `key` provided in `Options` object), instead of executing the same request again, Nuxt just returns the existing data.

In your case, it means that `data` Ref will have a correct value even before the `watch` is executed and thus from the `watch` POV the `data` will never change

You can easily test this by changing the line like this:

```
const { data, pending, error: err, refresh } = await useLazyFetch('/api/posts', { server: false });
```

(also requires changes in the template because the `data` will be null/undefined initially)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood the problem